# JWT - Access token signature validation using public key and pure PHP

Tags: php, validation, jwt, microsoft-graph-api, signature

*Sorry about the long post but I think it is best to provide as much information in an orderly fashion as possible.*

I have checked all questions that I found regarding this issue in Stack Overflow but I still haven't found an answer on how to do this.

I am writing my own class to use OAuth2 to connect to the Microsoft Graph and I can't find a way to validate the Access Token Signature (per RFC 7519 S.7.2).

---

### Note: The reason why I am trying to achieve this using pure PHP 7 is that I have tried all libraries available out there and they don't work for me.  They just don't run and they include too much bloatware.  Even Microsoft's GitHub repository.

Background:

I am able to retrieve the code reply from Microsoft.  I am able to decode the contents of the Token also.

I am using the following functions for that:

My configuration file contains:

```
// This is the Application ID from the Azure App Registration
$CLIENT_ID              = '<id goes here>';
// This is the Application Secret from the Azure App Registration
$CLIENT_SECRET          = '<secret goes here>';
// This is the Azure Active Directory tenant ID
$DIRECTORYID            = '<AAD tenant id goes here>';
// We are requesting that the response be an authorization code appended to the URL
$RESPONSE_TYPE          = 'code';
// User.Read        - to be able to get the user profile details
// offline_access   - to be able to get a refresh token
$SCOPE                  = 'user.read offline_access';
// We are asking for an authorization code which we will use to get an access token
$GRANT_TYPE             = 'authorization_code';
// The place in our app that will handle all of the OAuth2 process.
$REDIRECT_URL           = 'https://localhost/index.php';
// This is where we request a token from Microsoft
// MAKE SURE THAT IS IS USING VERSION 2.0 or the audience will not match
$TOKEN_URL              = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
// This is where we request authorization from Microsoft
$AUTH_URL               = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
// We will be pulling the user data from the Microsoft Graph v1.0
$USERDATAURL            = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/api/v1.0/me';
// This is where we pull the information for the URLs in this file
$OPENIDCONFIG_URL       = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration';
// This is where Microsoft publishes the public keys used to validate the tokens
$KEYS_URL               = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys';
```

1. To decode the base64 url contents:

```
public function base64_url_decode( $input )
{
    return base64_decode( str_replace(['-', '_'], ['+', '/'], $input ) );
}
```

2. To decode the access token received: 
   This returns an Array that contains

   1. 3 arrays

      - Token validity information
      - Header information
      - Body information
   2. 1 string

      - The base64_url decoded Signature

```
public function decode_AccessToken( $token )
{
    $info = [ 'token_type' => $token['token_type'], 
              'scope' => $token['scope'], 
              'expires_in' => $token['expires_in'], 
              'ext_expires_in' => $token['ext_expires_in'] ];

    // Explode the token to get each of the three parts inside it (Header, Body, Signature)
    $parts = explode(".", $token['access_token']);

    // Decode the header as an Array
    $header = (array)json_decode( $this->base64_url_decode( $parts[0] ) );

    // Decode the Body as an Array
    $body = (array)json_decode( $this->base64_url_decode( $parts[1] ) );

    // Decode the Signature
    $signature = $this->base64_url_decode( $parts[2] );

    // Return value
    return ['Info' => $info,'Header' => $header, 'Body' => $body, 'Signature' => $signature];
}
```

3. I retrieve the Public Key from the certificate chain [x5c] that is provided by the Microsoft keys endpoint:

```
public function get_SigningKeys()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Specify the URL to retrieve
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->keys_url);
    // Receive a JSON response
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True );
    // Do not validate SSL Certificates, by default SSL doesn't work with CURL.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // execute request
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );

    curl_close($ch);

    return (array)json_decode( $result );
}

public function get_PublicKey( $decodedToken )
{
    $keys = $this->get_SigningKeys();

    // The ID of the key that was used
    $keyID = $decodedToken['Header']['kid'];

    foreach( $keys['keys'] as $key )
    {
        if( $key->kid === $keyID )
        {
            // Create the Plain Text Certificate Chain
            $plainTextKeyCert  = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n";
            $plainTextKeyCert .= chunk_split( str_replace( " ", "", $key->x5c[0] ), 64, "\r\n" );
            $plainTextKeyCert .= "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
            // Read the Certificate Chain
            $cert              = openssl_x509_read( $plainTextKeyCert );
            // Extract the Public Key from the Certificate Chain
            $pubkey            = openssl_pkey_get_public( $cert );
            // Return the Public Key
            return openssl_pkey_get_details( $pubkey )['key'];
        }
    }

    return False;
}
```

4. I attempt to validate the Signature using openssl_verify: 
   Pre-Reqs:

   1. Payload:

      - Comprised of the base64 url decoded "header . body"
   2. Signature:

      - The base64_url decoded Signature
   3. The Public Key

      - Obtained in a previous step
   4. Confirmed that Microsoft uses RS256 to sign the token.

Action Taken: 
  1. Use openssl_verify to attempt to validate the signature.

```
// Do the actual signature verification
// Get the Public Key
$theKey = $this->get_PublicKey( $decoded );

list( $header, $body, $signature ) = explode( '.', $accessToken['access_token'] );

$payload = utf8_decode( $this->base64_url_decode( $header ) . '.' . $this->base64_url_decode( $body ) );

$verified = openssl_verify( $payload, $decoded['Signature'], $theKey, 'RSA-SHA256' );

echo '<br><br>Verified: ' . $verified;
```

This step fails.

I am not sure if: 
  1. I am not retrieving the Public Key properly.
  2. I am not using the proper algorithm in the openssl_verify function.
     [OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256, RSA-SHA256, sha256WithRSAEncryption]
  3. Other?

---

Certificate retrieved looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQbiJkXaenk61AKixVocnLRTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAt
MSswKQYDVQQDEyJhY2NvdW50cy5hY2Nlc3Njb250cm9sLndpbmRvd3MubmV0MB4X
DTE5MTAwNTAwMDAwMFoXDTI0MTAwNDAwMDAwMFowLTErMCkGA1UEAxMiYWNjb3Vu
dHMuYWNjZXNzY29udHJvbC53aW5kb3dzLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD
ggEPADCCAQoCggEBAJ2H9Y6Z+3BXUCtlbmXr6H5owYy15XTl3vdpOZLUkk4OV9LM
sB1phjNp+wgl28eAgrNNfu4BTVlHdR9x6NTrSiIapsYjzzEz4mOmRh1Bw5tJxit0
VEGn00/ZENniTjgeEFYgDHYwjrfZQ6dERBFiw1OQb2IG5f3KLtx92lUXeIZ7ZvTa
PkUpc4Qd6wQZmWgzPqWFocRsJATGyZzXiiXQUrc9cVqm1bws3P0lFBcqNtv+AKDY
KT5IRYLsyCkueQC9R6LUCsZVD7bVIkeQuA3iehJKIEAlk/e3j5E4VaCRs642ajb/
z9kByTl2xL2k0AeZGc8/Rcy7SQn0LBcJNZGp/SMCAwEAAaMhMB8wHQYDVR0OBBYE
FOLhl3BDPLNVYDe38Dp9JbUmd4kKMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAN4XwyqYfV
dMl0xEbBMa/OzSfIbuI4pQWWpl3isKRAyhXezAX1t/0532LsIcYkwubLifnjHHqo
4x1jnVqkvkFjcPZ12kjs/q5d1L0LxlQST/Uqwm/9/AeTzRZXtUKNBWBOWy9gmw9D
EH593sNYytGAEerbWhCR3agUxsnQSYTTwg4K9cSqLWzHX5Kcz0NLCGwLx015/Jc7
HwPJnp7q5Bo0O0VfhomDiEctIFfzqE5x9T9ZTUSWUDn3J7DYzs2L1pDrOQaNs/YE
kXsKDP1j4tOFyxic6OvjQ10Yugjo5jg1uWoxeU8pI0BxY6sj2GZt3Ynzev2bZqmj
68y0I9Z+NTZo
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Public Key retrieved looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnYf1jpn7cFdQK2VuZevo
fmjBjLXldOXe92k5ktSSTg5X0sywHWmGM2n7CCXbx4CCs01+7gFNWUd1H3Ho1OtK
IhqmxiPPMTPiY6ZGHUHDm0nGK3RUQafTT9kQ2eJOOB4QViAMdjCOt9lDp0REEWLD
U5BvYgbl/cou3H3aVRd4hntm9No+RSlzhB3rBBmZaDM+pYWhxGwkBMbJnNeKJdBS
tz1xWqbVvCzc/SUUFyo22/4AoNgpPkhFguzIKS55AL1HotQKxlUPttUiR5C4DeJ6
EkogQCWT97ePkThVoJGzrjZqNv/P2QHJOXbEvaTQB5kZzz9FzLtJCfQsFwk1kan9
IwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any stray white space in the key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I checked and the x5c from Microsoft doesn't have spaces and the public key ends up looking like a normal key with lines of 64 characters separated by line breaks.
It still doesn't work though.

Comment: Ok. Note that https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7468#page-2 is relevant to format.